# Vector Analysis: Chess

Tags: vectors

I came across the following question on a mechanics assignment:

> In chess, a knight makes L-shaped moves, two squares in one direction (horizontally or
>   vertically) followed by one square in a perpendicular direction. Determine whether or not
>   a knight can eventually reach every square on a 8 × 8 chess board. Hint: use vectors!

How would one go about it?

Comment: You can read more [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knight%27s_tour)

Comment: @Stefan4024: OP's question is much simpler, no need to visit every square **once**.

Comment: the knight's current position can be given by $\lambda\binom21+\lambda_1\binom{-2}1+\mu\binom12+\mu_1\binom{-1}2$

Comment: Can you design a series of moves that allows you to move one space up or one space to the right? then you can cover each square trivially.

Answer (score 1):

Take the knight to be in the top left position of a $3×3$ grid. This can be assumed because the edge is the only limiting factor and a configuration can be found by translation or rotation of a $3×3$ grid with the knight in the top left corner. We have

```
x 0 0    0 0 0    0 0 0    0 x 0
0 0 0 -> 0 0 x -> 0 0 0 -> 0 0 0
0 0 0    0 0 0    x 0 0    0 0 0
```

Thus we are able to move a knight arbitrarily on a chess board by repeating this pattern: moving to each square in a row, moving one column over then repeating the algorithm.

Comment: This move by one is called a unit vector and is an important concept